# Pass a derived class reference to a base class reference

Tags: c#, inheritance

> Pass a derived class reference to a base class reference

does this means that call a base class from the derived class, like the constructor triangle will call the base class?

```
class Shape {
public int width, height;
 public Shape(int x) { 
    width = height = x; 
    } 
}

class Triangle : Shape { 
 public string style;
  public Triangle(int x) : base(x) { 
    style = "isosceles";  
  } 
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will instruct the runtime to invoke that base Shape constructor before Triangle's.

The logic executes in this order:

1. Execute Shape(int x)
2. Execute Triangle(int x)

You can therefore direct calls to different constructor overloads if you have them.  Also note that if your base class has a parameterless constructor, there's essentially an implicit `base()` added if you do not specify one. That means if your base class does *not* have a parameterless constructor, all subclasses *must* make a valid `base(...parameters...)` in their constructor.

Also, you can use `this()` instead of base to target a constructor on the current subclass class.

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public MyBaseClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyBaseClass Parameterless");
    }

    public MyBaseClass(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyBaseClass Message: " + message);
    }
}

public class MySubClass
{
    public MySubClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MySubClass Parameterless");
    }

    public MySubClass(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MySubClass Message: " + message);
    }

    public MySubClass(bool someUselessFlag)
        : this()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MySubClass bool someUselessFlag constructor");
    }
}
```

The outputs would be:

```
var a = new MySubClass();
//outputs:
//MyBaseClass Parameterless
//MySubClass Parameterless

var b = new MySubClass("Hello World!");
//outputs:
//MyBaseClass Message: Hello World!
//MySubClass Message: Hello World!

var c = new MySubClass(true);
//outputs:
//MyBaseClass Parameterless
//MySubClass Parameterless
//MySubClass bool someUselessFlag constructor
```

Constructors chain on themselves until they eventually call the `Object()` base constructor.  That's why `var c = new MySubClass(true)` calls more than two constructors.

Comment: why in case of third constructor "var c = new MySubClass(true);" the two parameterless constructors were called ?

Comment: The first `this()` call chains it to `MySubClass()`, which in turn implicitly chains it to `base()`, which is `MyBaseClass()`.  The constructor can chain multiple times until it eventually calls down to `Object()`

Comment: I think this is an unfortunate misinterpretation of the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the book C# 4.0 - The Complete Reference by Herbert Schildt. I'll try to answer this question. I think the example of the question is incomplete. If this question was raised while reading one of Herbert Schildt's C# book. Then the example may be like this:

```
class Shape
{
    public int width, height;
    public Shape(int x)
    {
        width = height = x;
    }

    public Shape(Shape shape)
    {
        width = shape.width;
        height = shape.height;
    }
}

class Triangle : Shape
{
    public string style;
    public Triangle(int x)
        : base(x)
    {
        style = "isosceles";
    }
    public Triangle(Triangle triangle)
        : base(triangle)
    {
        style = triangle.style;
    }
}

class Draw
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle(5);
        Triangle triangle2 = new Triangle(triangle1);
    }
}
```

Here second constructor of the Triangle receives a Triangle object and pass this to the Shape constructor which is base type. And this is an example of passing a derived class reference to a base class reference. For more about this see page 299 of
[Herbert Schildt's book.](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0AaS4SEome8ODk4MDgyZGQtY2ZmNi00NDVmLTg2MmUtOWY1NzdiNDk3YjNh/edit)